# Why doesn't str.replace want to change this <> symbol?

Tags: javascript, html, str-replace

I need to change > to %3E .., if the > symbol is changed by another symbol, everything works fine.
How can I correct this?

```
<p id="demo">this > and this > symbol should be replaced.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/>/g, "%3E");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: `innerHtml` replaces `>` with `&gt;`. So your replace won't find anything. In this type of cases it's good to look at the data before asking yourself why some method doesn't work on it. In this case, a `console.log(str);` after setting it would have revealed the nature of your problem.

Comment: What happens if there’s other HTML in the `<p>`? Do you want to replace `>`s inside any attributes? If there won’t be any non-text HTML, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: if i change to test: (/> / g, "% 3E") in (/> / g, "RED") still does not work. He just doesn't want to change me < or >

Comment: @maja Have you seen my updated answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find `&gt;` (greater than) in Regex and replace with `<`.

[Read more here](https://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html)

```html
<p id="demo">this > and this > symbol should be replaced.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace(/\&gt\;/g, "\%3E");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need replace > to %3E

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ritesh Khandekar. I think your answer is definitely correct, but if I insert it into my notepad ++ where I code it doesn't work .. I'm wrong somewhere. I write after the test. I don't know why so many minuses on the question. :(

Comment: @maja, why are you expecting any DOM method to work inside notepad++? notepad++ is a text editor, not a browser. There is no DOM in notepad++ and therefore you shouldn't expect web javascript scripts to magically work just because the contents of your file happens to be the source of a web page. However, if you open that file in a browser, the script will work correctly.

Comment: @maja I think you should take care of everything in Regex, even  a space. And i think community want you to edit your question and be specific on one problem.